# A question from a math olympiad book

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

. Find the sum of the 5th powers of the roots of the equation $x^3+3x+9=0$
I tried using vieta relations and got that if the roots are a , b , c then

$a^4+b^4+c^4 = 36$. I dont know how to proceed forward .Please help

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/725028/975531) seems to answer your question in the general case

Comment: thanks it worked

Comment: the sum of fourth powers also does not look right to me, shouldn't it be $18$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of fifth power of roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725028/sum-of-fifth-power-of-roots)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quite simple solution which is also much easier than the recommendations linked in the comment section:

For any solution $t \in \{a,b,c\}$ of $x^3 + 3x+9 = 0$ it follows:

$$t^3 = -3t-9 \Rightarrow t^5 = -3t^3-9t^2 \quad (1)$$

Now, note that

$$t(t^2+3)=-9 \Rightarrow t^2 = -\frac 9t -3 \quad (2)$$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ together gives
$$t^5 = -3(-3t-9)-9\left(-\frac 9t -3\right) = 9t + \frac{81}t+54 \quad (3)$$

Noting that $\frac 1t$ is a solution to $x^3+\frac 13 x^2 +\frac 19 = 0$, you finally obtain from $(3)$ using Vieta (sum of zeros):

$$a^5+b^5+c^5 = 9\cdot 0 + 81\cdot \left(-\frac 13\right) + 3\cdot 54 = 135$$

Comment: Great thinking . This is a far easier solution than i expected.